# How to replace a button on click using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button currently available with an id :

```
<input type="button" id="show_button"  value="Show" />
```

What I want is that..onclicking the  button , the value of the button will be changed to "Hide" and it's id will be changed to "hide_button".. And on clicking the hide button it's value will be changed to "Show" and it's id will change to "show_button"..How can I achieve that?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to change the id?

Comment: It isn't good to change id (change class with `toggleClass`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i don't know why you want to change the id since we can get what you want without changing the ids..
try this

```
 $('#show_button').click(function(){
     var $this=$(this);
     $this.val(($this.val()=="Show")?"Hide":"Show");
 });
```

this is better since you don't have to use two click event handler for both the ids..

and if incase you need to change the ids.. then use on event delegation ..

```
 $(document).on('click','#show_button',function(){
     var $this=$(this);
     $this.prop('id','hide_button');
     $this.val("Hide"); //OR  $this.val("Hide") //if you are using input type="button"
 });

$(document).on('click','#hide_button',function(){
     var $this=$(this);
      $this.prop('id','show_button');
     $this.val("Show"); //OR  $this.val("Hide") //if you are using input type="button"
 });
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/stEd8/2/)

Comment: I want to change the id.. within the id i have a php variable.. id="show_button'.$show.'" .. I don't need two buttons..but using one button if I can change the button id then I can have two functionality... Only changing the value wouldn't help.

Comment: i have no idea why i got downvotes for this... anyways... @user2605321 welcome.... glad this helped.. HAPPY CODING  :)

Comment: You got downvotes? I got downvotes..and I have no idea why.! :p

Answer (score 1):

You can  change value  using

```
  $('#show_button').val('hide');
```

You can  change id  using

```
 $('#show_button').attr('id','hide_button');
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Jquery Javascript library:

```
$('body').on('click', '#show_button', function() {
  $(this).attr('id', 'hide_button').val('Hide');
});

$('body').on('click', '#hide_button', function() {
  $(this).attr('id', 'show_button').val('Show');
});
```

Comment: This would only work the first time as you are not using delegation.

Comment: "on" IS delegation :)

Comment: on allows for delegation with the use of the selector parameter - the way you wrote it does not use delegation: http://jsfiddle.net/stEd8/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body').on('click', '#show_button, #hide_button', function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        isShow = $this.attr('id') == 'show_button';

    if (isShow) {
        $this.attr('id', 'hide_button').val('Hide');
    }
    else {
        $this.attr('id', 'show_button').val('Show');
    }
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sW49u/

Answer (score 1):

One solution for your question is have 2 inputs, that you toggle between. I don't like changing/renaming id's principle.

Check this **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8hYeN/)**.

html

```
<input type="button" id="show_button"  value="Show" />
<input type="button" id="hide_button"  value="Hide" style="display:none;" />
```

jQuery

```
$('input').click(
    function(){
       $('input').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/TjaBR/

```
$('body').on('click', '#process', function() {
   $(this).toggleClass('hidden');
   $(this).val($(this).hasClass('hidden') ? 'Hide' : 'Show');
});
```

Comment: I said, that it's bad practise to change id in a comment

Comment: But it's not this problem.

Comment: I think everybody, who'll find this question have to know, that it isn't good. Don't you agree?